# Is there any API available that could return the width of a street?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to get a rough description of the streets/roads type. For example when using routing algorithms, we would like to avoid sending long vehicles to inappropriate roads (narrow streets). In Google Maps highways and narrow roads are quite different and the difference is presented very clear in high level. It would be nice if we could get this information through an API to optimize the routing algorithms.

Comment: This has been voted down at least twice (I voted it up), with no reason given in the comments.  The request seems reasonable, and the answer could be useful. 
 What is wrong with this question?

Comment: I have seen other maps solutions that provide this kind of information and this is why I'm asking for. Especially in rural areas this is quite useful to avoid deadlocks, thus I was expecting that such a feature would be implemented by a Google Maps API.

Comment: @RayButterworth See the help-center: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. "

Comment: @piet.t, It would have saved time and trouble if at least the first person to vote it down had added a comment saying this.  (Perhaps it shouldn't be possible to downvote a question that doesn't have any comments.)

Comment: @piet.t, on the other hand, this question isn't asking for any of those things you listed.  It is asking whether Google Maps provides an API.  That isn't asking for an opinion or anything controversial.

Comment: @RayButterworth "It is asking whether Google Maps provides an API" - no, it doesn't, it asks "if there are any tools"....

Comment: @piet.t, I've edited (pending review) the question to remove the use of the offending word "tools".  The Title and the concluding line ask for an API, as they always did.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `google-maps` tag, I assume that you'd also want this feature in Google Maps API, there are currently no features for this in the Google Maps API, however, you may file a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188848&template=787422) in the Issue Tracker for Google Maps APIs in order for the engineers to review the feasibility of your request.